# Validar maxlength de un input según la opción que se elija en el select

Tags: select, input

Tengo dos select los cuales actúan dinámicamente para elegir el tipo de documento de un ciudadano o compañía. En el primer select tengo los 3 tipos de documentos que existen en mi país y según el que elija el usuario el segundo select despliega los prefijos de abreviación en letras usados para esos tipos de documentos,
ejemplo si elije C.I.= es la cédula o dni del ciudadano y existen dos letras para ese tipo de documento, en ese momento el select de abajo cambiara y mostrara estas letras V(venezolano)8 números, E(extranjero)8 números,
Si elije R.I.F es una persona juridica, empresa ó gobierno por ejemplo un rif de empresa comienza con J(Juridico)9 números, G(Gobierno) 9 números
Si elije pasaporte cambiara Pasaporte el select de abajo mostrara P(Pasaporte)10 números.

Según lo explicado acá arriba, lo que necesito en si es que según la opción que el usuario elija en los select quiero que el input cambie su maxlenght, si elije cédula que sería V o E quiero que el maxlenght del input se ponga en 8, si elije pasaporta P quiero que el maxlenght del input cambie a 10 etc..etc.

Aquí el fragmento de mi formulario donde pido el tipo del documento con los select y luego el input

```
</div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="tipo">ELIGE TU TIPO DE DOCUMENTO</label>
                    <select name="tipo" class="form-control" onchange="cambia()">
                    <option value="1">C.I.
                    <option value="2">R.I.F
                    <option value="3">Pasaporte
                    </select>
                     </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="letras" class="form-control">
                    <option value="V">V
                    <option value="E">E
                    </select>
                </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="documento">Docuemento</label>
                    <input type="text" name="documento" placeholder="escribe el número de cédula, rif ó pasaporte según sea el caso" id="documento" class="form-control" required>
                </div>
```

Aquí la función que genera el dinamismo entre los select

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
        var letras_1 = new Array ("V", "E");
        var letras_2 = new Array ("V", "E", "J", "P", "G");
        var letras_3 = new Array ("P");
  
        
        function cambia(){
            var tipo;
         
            tipo= document.registropago.tipo[document.registropago.tipo.selectedIndex].value;
  
            if(tipo!=0){
                mis_letras=eval("letras_" + tipo);
                num_letras=mis_letras.length;  
                document.registropago.letras.length = num_letras;
           
                for(i=0; i<num_letras; i++){
                    document.registropago.letras.options[i].value=mis_letras[i];
                    document.registropago.letras.options[i].text=mis_letras[i];
                }
                }else{
                    document.registropago.letras.length = 1;
                    document.registropago.letras.options[0].value="-";
                    document.registropago.letras.options[0].text="-";
                }
                document.registropago.letras.options[0].selected = true;
                
            }
        </script>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La opción más eficaz que se me ocurre es la siguiente:

La primera es que cuando creas los `option` de tu `select` que, me imagino que tienen un dato relacionado sobre la cantidad de caracteres permitidos con los que puede contar. De esta manera puedes contar valores de tipo `data` para cada `option`. De esta manera:

```
<option value!="{{ $doc->id }}" data-lenght!="{{ $doc->lenght }}"> C.I.
```

Y de esta manera, en tu JS, puedes tener algo como lo siguiente:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('select[name="tipo"]').on('change', function() { // Se activa en el cambio del primer select
    var tipo = $(this).val();
    var selected_lenght = $('select[name="tipo"] option:selected').data('lenght');
    var letras = $('select[name="letras"]');
        
    switch(tipo) { // Suponiendo que el valor de los option empieza con 1 y son consecutivos
        case "1": 
            // Aquí, para este caso, independientemente del segundo select, la longitud del otro campo va tener un valor, así que le asignamos el data del primer select (Siempre 8)
            $('input[name="documento"]').val('');
            $('input[name="documento"]').attr('maxlength', selected_lenght);
                        
            // Ahora ponemos los nuevos option del segundo select
            letras.empty(); // Vaciamos sus option y agregamos nuevas
            letras.append('<option value="V">V </option>');
            letras.append('<option value="E">E </option>');

            break;
        case "2": 
            // Aquí, aplica igual que el anterior (Siempre 9)
            $('input[name="documento"]').val('');
            $('input[name="documento"]').attr('maxlength', selected_lenght);

            // Ahora ponemos los nuevos option del segundo select
            letras.empty(); // Vaciamos sus option y agregamos nuevas
            letras.append('<option value="J"> Jurídico </option>');
            letras.append('<option value="G"> Gobierno </option>');

            break;
        case "3":
            // Aquí, aplica igual (Siempre 10)
            $('input[name="documento"]').val('');
            $('input[name="documento"]').attr('maxlength', selected_lenght);

            // Ahora ponemos los nuevos option del segundo select
            letras.empty(); // Vaciamos sus option y agregamos nuevas
            letras.append('<option value="P" selected> Pasaporte </option>'); // Le ponemos selected ya que será la única opción a elegir, no hay de otra

            break;
        default:
            // En caso de algún nuevo tipo de documento y no esté validado aquí
    }
        
});

});
```

Y listo.

Te dejo el ejemplo funcionando [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/2xdy4v70/6/)

Comment: Gracias por responder, no soy muy experimentado en javascript apenas estoy aprendiendo, la primera interrogante del código que me colocas es ¿dónde asigno el valor del máximo de caracteres? y segundo, cuando pego la función dentro de mi script los select dejan de hacer el dinamismo.

Comment: El valor del número de caracteres para cada opción, se puede asignar en un columna de tu base datos o, si solamente tienes esas opciones "hardcodeadas" puedes poner el valor directamente como `data-lenght="16"`. En el caso del dinamismo que mencionas, no había notado ese otro `select`, qué función que afecta el `input`?

Comment: Si, yo le asigno el valor directamente en la bd pero el más largo que en este caso es el pasarporte, porque en la bd existe un solo campo que es documento allí se guarda cualquiera de las opciones por eso necesito que se valide directamente en el input. Con respecto al dinamismo cuando pego esto $('select').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="documento"]').attr('maxlength', $(this).data('lenght'));
});

Comment: dentro de mis script los select ya no cambian

Comment: Eso dos select son dinámicos ségun lo que elijas en el primero el segundo cambia

Comment: Crees que puedas editar tu pregunta, por favor? Para que expliques de mejor manera los casos en los que cuando cambia el primer select, qué cosa debería de "auto seleccionarse" o crear nuevas opciones para el segundo select :) Te lo agradecería para entender mejor

Comment: Perfecto ya lo hago, gracias

Comment: O sea, si selecciono Pasaporte, qué pasa con el segundo select, se borran sus opciones y se ponen nuevas, se selecciona una opción de las que ya estaban, cosas así

Comment: Ya cambie la pregunta

Comment: si correcto si presiona pasaporte se borra las que estaban y solo aparece P en el segundo select

Comment: Y P que es el prefijo de pasaporte en mi país, pues aquí un pasaporte tiene 10 números, entonces necesito que el maxlenght cambie a 10, si elije C.I. en el primer select que su prefijo en el segundo select es V pues aquí una cédula o dni o como lo conozcas en tu país tiene 8 números, pues el maxlenght del input debe cambiar a 8

Comment: Listo, ya quedó, en el mismo código explico con los comentarios

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo utilizado y por responder, pero insisto en algo,¿dónde le dices al input que debe aceptar solo 8 o 9 o 10 caracteres?

Comment: La primera línea de cada `case` hace referencia al campo de texto donde ingresas el número de documento. La función `attr()` te permite modificar/consultar los atributos de ese elemento, en caso de que incluyas dos parámetros, te permite modificar ese atributo, `maxlenght` es un atributo y así es como se va modificando el número de caracteres permitidos. Igualmente puedes poner un `minlenght` para que la validación sea aún más precisa

Comment: Gracias una vez más, pero no le agarro el hilo a tu script lo coloco y no hace el dinamismo de los select y tampoco válida el input

Comment: Edité mi respuesta y te dejo el ejemplo en JSFiddle, está funcionando y todo bien. Considera marcar mi respuesta como correcta y votar arriba, por favor, saludos :)

Comment: Gracias he probado tu ejemplo en JSFiddle, y fuciona el dinamismo de los select pero el input sigue aceptando más valores de los validados, si elijo una cédula, un pasaporte o un juridico puedo poner la cantidad de valores que quiera y debería dejar escribir solo el número de valores de cada documento

Comment: Revisa de nuevo

Comment: Excelente ahora si, muchas gracias amigo